# how to scroll an element using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

could you please tell me how to scroll an element using javascript? Actually, I have created a demo application. I can be left when "left is positive" but not able to scroll when the left is negative.

I created two cases. First cases working fine. When I click on the button it scrolls to 100 px. But in the second case, I am not able to scroll negative why? here is my code

```
function handler(){
 
  document.querySelector(".p").scroll({
    left:100,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  })
  
}

document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", handler, false)


function handler2(){
 
  document.querySelector(".p2").scroll({
    left:-100,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  })
  
}

document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click", handler2, false)
```

https://jsbin.com/mahohoquge/edit?html,js,output

1. **case 1: is working fine**

**

1.
2. **case 2: not working fine**

**

any idea? how to scroll

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  case : 1
  <div class="p">
    <div class="b r">1</div>
    <div class="b g">1</div>
     <div class="b bl">1</div>
  </div>
  <button id="button">move</button>
  <hr/>
  
    case : 2
  <div class="p2">
    <div class="b r2">1</div>
    <div class="b g2">1</div>
     <div class="b bl2">1</div>
  </div>
  <button id="button2">move left</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little more about what is the effect you want to achieve?

Comment: no effect , but move to previous slide same as example one

Comment: if you see first example next slide display in button click.can we do the same thing in second example

Comment: In otherwords blue is coming from right in example one.I want it should come from left in second example

Comment: I am not sure but the jquery double scroll is may be useful for you.

[https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Double-Scrollbar-For-Scrollable-Container-jQuery-DoubleScroll.html]

Comment: I am using pure javascript

Comment: I don't think it's possible, because by definition it scrolls to the left or top (right to left, bottom to top) as you can see in the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ScrollToOptions. As well, if there's a negative value, the function returns null, see here: https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#extensions-to-the-document-interface.

Answer (score 2):

if you're trying to achieve the carousel effect, it would be much effective to use the transform: translate() function instead of using the scroll.
https://jsbin.com/kiditahado/edit?html,css,js,output this edited snippet from your original one shows how you could do it.

```
let start = 0;
function handler(step){
 const p = document.querySelectorAll(".p div");
  start+=step
  p.forEach(el=>{

  el.style.transform =`translate(${start}px,0)`

  })

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The underlying problem is that u can't scoll into negative values. The only solution witch comes to my mind is to reverse the blocks and scroll from the right side.

So css becomes:

```
.p2{
  position:relative;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  overflow:hidden;
  left:50%;
}
.b2{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  position:absolute
}
.r2 {
  background-color:red;
  left:200px;
}

.bl2 {
  background-color:blue;
  left:100px;
}

.g2 {
  background-color:green;
  left:0px;
}
```

And JS becomes:

```
function handler2(){  
  document.querySelector(".p2").scroll({
    left:100,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  })     
}

// start from the other side
document.querySelector(".p2").scroll({left:200});

document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click", handler2, false)
```

Comment: any better way ..! ?

Comment: Sure, skip javascript and use CSS animations instead.

Comment: can you also share that example also

Comment: Well, it still really depends on what is your use case. Do you want it for some button animation, banner animation? ...or do you want to move whole page content with it?